# Waypoints for stores, barber shops, ammo shops, etc. are not showing up

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

My son has GTA Online on the PS4. We have the map on the bottom of the screen but shops (barber shops, ammo stores, clothing stores, etc.) are not showing up on the side of the screen. All that shows up is his apartment, garages, and CEO business. How can we fix this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or something alike that shows the problem? next to that you can cycle what you want to see with the legenda, maybe that's the problem and you son selected only things he owns?

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible you have details disabled in the Map. Press the start button, or whatever the Map button is bound to, then enable details in the bottom right (It says a keybinding)

Answer (score 1):

Hit and hold your touch pad until a menu pops up then  select hide options select other you can fix it from there.

1. Hold touch pad
2. Select hide options
3. Select other
4. Change all other to custom

It should preshow everything.

Answer (score -1):

I've also encountered this, It will happen when you're about to lose connection online, It's a bug with GTA servers, you'll just have to wait for the fix.